# Android studio error inflating constraint layout

Tags: android

Android studio drops 
"android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout"
error when i run my app on Android Marshmallow or below. It perfectly works on nougat and oreo
I added "implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'" as i saw it in other answers but it still not works

xml:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/soros3"
android:padding="0dp"
tools:co0-ntext=".MainActivity">
```

please help

Comment: Is `tools:context=".MainActivity"`

Answer (score 1):

ok
So I removed the background of the layout and removed the

```
tools:co0-ntext=".MainActivity"
```

line and it works.
I don't really know why but it works

Comment: That's not a valid attribute tag anyway